# How to stop Javascript from showing default image and only text for link?

Tags: javascript, html

The Javascript below has a default image, but I would like display text "only text url" for this link instead of this button at this link http://developer.mixi.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/bt_check_1.gif that this script defaults to.   Is this possible?

[image]

```
<div>
<a href="http://mixi.jp/share.pl" class="mixi-check-button" data-key="some-data-key" data-url="http://someurl.com">only text url </a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.mixi.jp/js/share.js"></script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is legal (it may not be legal to embed this script in your site if you make modifications to it), we can decompress the script using an [online JavaScript beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org). The result is this:

> http://www.jsfiddle.net/T4Rrh/

The bit we're interested in is the last `for` loop there, where each button is processed. We can safely remove a most of the image generation and protocol sniffing (an unnecessary practice, by the way) to reduce the weight of the code:

```
var type = (button["button"] || "button-1.png").split("-");
var prefix = ("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://mixi.jp/" : "http://static.mixi.jp/";
if (!type || type.length < 2) type = ["button", "1.png"];
if (type[1].indexOf(".") == -1) type[1] += ".png";
var src = (type[0] == "button") ? [prefix, "img/basic/mixicheck_entry/bt_check_", type[1]] : (type[0] == "icon") ? [prefix, "img/basic/mixicheck_entry/icon_mixi_", type[1]] : [prefix, "img/basic/mixicheck_entry/bt_check_1.png"];
src = src.join("");
```

and

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.setAttribute("src", src);
img.style.border = "0";
var element = button.element;
for (var j = element.childNodes.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    element.removeChild(element.childNodes[j]);
}
element.appendChild(img);
```

should be both removed. You can then minify and save the code, then serve it yourself in your page. Here's what the cleaned up code looks like: http://www.jsfiddle.net/XrYLX/

---

**Second Method:**

Using CSS, we first remove the part of the JavaScript which removes all child nodes of the button element, so the text inside the button is not removed:

```
for (var j = element.childNodes.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    element.removeChild(element.childNodes[j]);
}
```

We then apply some CSS to hide the image:

```
.mixi-check-button img {
    display: none;
}
```

See: http://www.jsfiddle.net/T4Rrh/1/.

Comment: @Yi Jiang - Thank you for editing this question as I am unable to add buttons as I am new to stackoverflow.  I tried this and the "only text url" shows up, but it does not connect with the SNS resulting in an "no data" error.  Is there something in the code above that needs to be sent to this SNS?

Comment: @tokyowp I'm not entirely sure what you're asking for here, but the code above should not affect the data been sent to the server unless the HTTP request for the image itself is used server-side to obtain information, in which case you might want to use CSS to hide the image instead. However, I don't think that's the case - all information seems to be sent through the query string inside the link.

Comment: @Yi Jiang.  I would like to display "Mixiチェック" in text instead of this button.  How would I use CSS to block the image from showing and just the text?

Comment: I think the question might be best as the Javascript above is for a Japanese SNS (Mixi) sharing button similar to adding the Facebook like button onto a website.  It displays this button, but I would like to display text instead of the image.  I have tried adding img css to the div to display:none, but the image and text do not show.  How would I display the text and not the image in CSS?

Comment: @tokyowp Because the JavaScript actually removes all child nodes (including your textnode) in the button element before inserting the image. I have doubts though that the modifications to the JavaScript is the root of the problem. It shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: @Yi Jiang.  So if I cannot edit the Javascript and the CSS, I really cannot do anything to just show the text instead of this button?

Comment: @tokyowp Well, you can inject the text into the button *after* the original JavaScipt's done with it, but that's quite extreme...

Comment: @Yi Jiang.  Sounds pretty extreme for a button, but I have all my share buttons from other SNS in text and did not want this to be the only one that is an image.  Guess there`s no easy way around this.

Comment: @Yi Jiang.  Your Second Method worked!  Though I am concerned about the legality.  Unfortunately, you have to register your credit card in order to ask technical questions.

Comment: @tokyowp Search around a bit more. Also, what sort of weird website will require your credit card info to ask questions?

Comment: @Yi Jiang.  Truly a weird site, but one of the top SNS in Japan.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Yi Jiang:  Been having problem with something I thought you might be able to help me with.  Want to give it a shot?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068274/how-to-code-php-function-or-set-parameters-to-return-no-height-values-for-images

Answer (score 0):

Copy that script to your site and remove `element.appendChild(img);` at the beginning of the last line.