# what css or html causes the safari browser to not show an image?

Tags: html, css, image

There's supposed to be an image in the center under the text "GIANT MANGO".  It shows in Firefox, Chrome, and IE, but it does not show in the Safari browser.

http://giantmango.com/vote-for-artist-charity-contest-44-2581

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Displays fine for me. In Chrome and Safari, but I'm on a Mac, not that it should matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't show up initially with Chrome 9 on Linux either. If you drill down through the developer tools, the computed style for that image shows its height and width to be 1px in both directions. If I remove the `max-height: 100%` from the `div.post-body p img, div.post-body p object` rule, the image appears.

While I can't explain this (I haven't the time to look at it in-depth) I hope this puts you on the right track towards debugging this.

Comment: I can`t believe Safari has this problem.

Comment: You seemed to pick this up pretty quickly.  Want to give this a shot?  My images are for some reason being set to 200px x 200px.  What is setting it?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068274/how-to-code-php-function-or-set-parameters-to-return-no-height-values-for-images

Answer (score 0):

On the `single-wrapper` div, is there a `padding-top` of 1000px coming in somehow, that's pushing the contained div down? (the image appears in my safari, it's just far down the page).

Comment: I just confirmed it's there in your `style.css`. Safari is obeying this and padding the div 1000px high before displaying its content (including the image).